# Keep getting an error when using OledbConnection

Tags: oledbconnection

I can't seem to set up a connection when I attempt to open up an excel 2010 spreadsheet (xlsx file).  I don't know what I am doing wrong.  I appear to be following the tutorials to a T.

Here is the code I am trying...

```
        static string fileName = "C:\\Code\\UPMC\\ISD\\EADIS\\UPMC.ISD.EADIS.ACO.ACOBackLoad\\App_Data\\Example ACO Epic Data File.xlsx";
        try
        {
            //Workbook workBook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            //Worksheet wkSheet = (Worksheet)_excelApp.Worksheets[1];
            //OLEObject oleObject = wkSheet.OLEObjects(Type.Missing);
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\""))
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
```

These are my references.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
```

This would be the exception.

```
The type initializer for 'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace' threw an     exception.
```

Message
     Unrecognized configuration section authentication.
I get the impression I need to set up an app.config.  Guess I need to find some better tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem today after added the <appSettings>
When i remove them, it works.

<appSettings> added on incorrect position will cause this error.

Comment: It was something like that for me to.  I just forgot to answer my own question.  Thanks for bringing this topic back up.